# Jquery autocomplete to get values in JSON

Tags: jquery, html, autocomplete

Below is my JSON object

```
var data = [{"city":"Oslo","cityCode":"OSL","airport":"Oslo - All airports","airportCode":"OSL","country":"Norway","localName":"Gardermoen","europeFlag":true,"airlines":["SK","WF"],"distance":0.0}]
```

I am trying to do autocomplete with the JSON data. On typing OSL(cityode) i would like to display the OSLO(city) in dropdown and viceversa.

I have used below code but its returning empty value

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var data = [{"city":"Oslo","cityCode":"OSL","airport":"Oslo - All airports","airportCode":"OSL","country":"Norway","localName":"Gardermoen","europeFlag":true,"airlines":["SK","WF"],"distance":0.0}]

    $("#meta-area").autocomplete({
        source:data,
        select: function(e, ui) {
            e.preventDefault() 
            $("#meta_search_ids").val(ui.item.cityCode);

            $(this).val(ui.item.city);
        }
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<input type='text' size='20' id='meta-area' />
<input type='hidden' id='meta_search_ids' value='' />
```

Please help me out to get the values.Thanks in advance

Comment: why don't you directly use city name for auto complete?

Comment: some cases i may search with citycode and some times i may search with cityname i.e city

Comment: I think your requirement cannot be done by jquery ui

Answer (score 0):

I hope this would help you, I just did some basic implementation.I hope this is the kind of solution you are looking for...

Note - I didn't handle any exception

```js
var data;

$(document).ready(function(){

     data = [{"city":"Oslo","cityCode":"OSL","":"Oslo - All airports","airportCode":"OSL","country":"Norway","localName":"Gardermoen","europeFlag":true,"airlines":["SK","WF"],"disairporttance":0.0},{"city":"Colombo","cityCode":"CMB","":"Oslo - All airports","airportCode":"OSL","country":"Norway","localName":"Gardermoen","europeFlag":true,"airlines":["SK","WF"],"disairporttance":0.0},{"city":"Oruwala","cityCode":"OSS","":"Oslo - All airports","airportCode":"OSL","country":"Norway","localName":"Gardermoen","europeFlag":true,"airlines":["SK","WF"],"disairporttance":0.0}]




});

$('#meta-area').keyup(function(){
$('#meta_search_ids').val('');
var searchText = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
if(searchText == '') return;
var filterData = $.grep(data,function(ele, index){
return ele.cityCode.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText) != -1;
})

if(filterData[0].city == 'undefined'){
$('#meta_search_ids').val('');
}
else{
$('#meta_search_ids').val(filterData[0].city);
}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' Placeholder="Search" size='20' id='meta-area' />
<input type='text'  Placeholder="Suggestion"  id='meta_search_ids' value='' />
```